# How to use pipe in input text using ngModel Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, input-mask

I had dropdown component (list of credit card) that bind dropdown value on `input`, Using `ngModel` I managed to bind dropdown value on input, then I need to display credit card number on input field that looks like bullet special character:

```
4444 •••• •••• 4444
```

by using `pipe`, I had managed to bind it on dropdown component but got a problem when bind it to `input` because of `ngModel`, this is what I had tried:

**mask.pipe.ts**

```
transform(value: string, showMask :boolean): string {

    if (typeof value === "number") {
        value = JSON.stringify(value);
    }

    if (!showMask || value.length < 16) {
        return value;
    }

    return `${value.substr(0, 4)} ${'&#x25cf;'.repeat(4)} ${'&#x25cf;'.repeat(4)} ${value.substr(value.length - 4, value.length)}`;
}
```

**html component**

```
  <input placeholder="value"
    [ngModel]="selectedCard.value | maskInput: true"
    (ngModelChange)="selectedCard.value = $event"type="text">
```

and the output is :

```
1111 &#x25cf;&#x25cf;&#x25cf;&#x25cf; &#x25cf;&#x25cf;&#x25cf;&#x25cf; 1111
```

this is my [stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kaxjuy?file=src/app/app.component.ts), is there any suggestion on how to solve this, or better practice ?

Answer (score 0):

Your approach seems perfect,

Just replace `&#x25cf` with   `●`

Like this:

```
 return `${value.substr(0, 4)} ${'●'.repeat(4)} ${'●'.repeat(4)} ${value.substr(value.length - 4, value.length)}`;
```

[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uwlbch?embed=1&file=src/app/mask-input.pipe.ts)

Comment: HTML codes exist for a reason ... Any person not using the correct font on their browser will have an error in their input with that (blank squares)

Comment: @hafizi definitely not.

Comment: @Maryannah 's answer is awesome :) Use that

Answer (score 0):

Use the unicode characters : [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-shhusi?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

```
  transform(value: string, args?: any): any {
    const start = value.substr(0, 4);
    const end = value.substr(-4, 4);
    const bullets = '\u2022';
    return `${start} ${bullets.repeat(4)} ${bullets.repeat(4)} ${end}`;
  }
```

**[Unicodes codes](https://unicode-table.com/en/)**